# Error when trying to query neo4j database using golang and graphql

Tags: go, neo4j, graphql, go-gin

I tried making a simple server for graphql and go using a neo4j database but I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "movieByTitle": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "User Error: expected iterable, but did not find one for field Query.movieByTitle.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "movieByTitle"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

when I make a request. This is my graphql field:

```
var getMovieByTitle = &graphql.Field{
    Type: graphql.NewList(models.MovieType),
    Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
        "title": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
            Type: graphql.String,
        },
    },
    Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
        title := params.Args["title"].(string)

        configuration := data.ParseConfiguration()
        driver, err := configuration.NewDriver()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer data.UnsafeClose(driver)

        session := driver.NewSession(neo4j.SessionConfig{
            AccessMode:   neo4j.AccessModeRead,
            DatabaseName: configuration.Database,
        })
        defer data.UnsafeClose(session)

        movie, err := session.ReadTransaction(func(tx neo4j.Transaction) (interface{}, error) {
            records, err := tx.Run(
                `MATCH (movie:Movie {title:$title})
                  OPTIONAL MATCH (movie)<-[r]-(person:Person)
                  WITH movie.title as title,
                         collect({name:person.name,
                         job:head(split(toLower(type(r)),'_')),
                         role:r.roles}) as cast 
                  LIMIT 1
                  UNWIND cast as c 
                  RETURN title, c.name as name, c.job as job, c.role as role`,
                map[string]interface{}{"title": title})
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            var result models.Movie
            for records.Next() {
                record := records.Record()
                title, _ := record.Get("title")
                result.Title = title.(string)
                name, _ := record.Get("name")
                job, _ := record.Get("job")
                role, _ := record.Get("role")
                switch role.(type) {
                case []interface{}:
                    result.Cast = append(result.Cast, models.Person{Name: name.(string), Job: job.(string), Role: data.ToStringSlice(role.([]interface{}))})
                default: // handle nulls or unexpected stuff
                    result.Cast = append(result.Cast, models.Person{Name: name.(string), Job: job.(string)})
                }
            }
            return result, nil
        })
        if movie == nil {
            log.Println(movie)
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("movie not found")
        }
        fmt.Println(movie)
        return movie, nil
    },
}
```

I am using gin to run the server. I tried running the same query with an http endpoint instead of graphql and I got the expected response. How can I fix the error? I am using the example movie dataset in neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the type of the `Query.movieByTitle` field is an array of Movie objects, but is your resolver returning a single movie instead of a list/array?

In other GraphQL server implementations, this is typically handled gracefully, not sure about the Go GraphQL implementation you're using.

Comment: I have changed the field to remove the list type and now it works. Thanks!